# Program to Download all PDF files from webpage

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, web-scraping, download

I am trying to write a Python 3 program which will download all the PDF files from [this](https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339#518552) website.
I currently have two codes but none of them work.

```
import requests 
import urllib.request
import urllib.request
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339#556573.html'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
      print("Success")
else:
      print("Failure")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for one_a_tag in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)')):
    link = one_a_tag['href']
    download_url = 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339'+ link
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

The program runs without giving any output or stopping.

An the second program

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import urllib
url="https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339#518552"
response = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(.pdf)'))
url_list = []
for el in links:
    if(el['href'].startswith('http')):
    url_list.append(el['href'])
else:
    url_list.append("https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339/" + el['href'])

print(url_list)
for url in url_list:
     print(url)
     request.urlretrieve(url, r'C:/Downloads')
```

For both programs if I add a second argument `(filename)` to `urlretrieve` where PDF files should download it gives me

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Downloads' error.

(I have tried multiple things to solve this error, it does not work, I have Windows). If I do not have the second argument, the second program keeps going on and producing output but does not download.

Could anybody help please?

Comment: On some PCs the C:\ drive is locked down. Can you save it to a D:\ drive or other?

Comment: I only have C:\ drive

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `"C:\Downloads"`? The docs for urllib say that `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` is considered a legacy function, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In most instances, the C:/ drive is locked down try changing to a different drive as X:/ or D:/ or redirect `C:/Downloads` to `C:\Users\Name\Downloads`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no mistake in using your code, but the PDF is on the next page. Give you an example of using other frameworks for reference only.

```
import io
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
class PdfSpider(Spider):
  name = 'stlouisfed'
  concurrencyPer1s = 5
  allowed_domains = ['stlouisfed.org']
  start_urls = ['https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1339']
  refresh_urls = True

  def afterResponse(self, response, url, error=None, extra=None):
    try:
      # save pdf
      if(response.code==200 and url.find('.pdf')>0):
        name = 'data'+url[url.rindex('/'):]
        file = io.open(name, "wb")
        file.write(response.read())
        file.close()
        return None
      else: # If it's not a pdf, leave it to the frame
        return Spider.afterResponse(self, response, url, error)
    except Exception as err:
      print (err)

  def extract(self,url,html,models,modelNames):
    urls = SimplifiedDoc(html).listA(url=url['url']).containsOr(['/pdf/','.pdf'],attr='url')
    if(urls):
      self.saveUrl(urls)
    return True

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(PdfSpider()) # Start
```

Comment: What do you mean the PDF is on the next page?

Comment: The link in your url_list is not a PDF link. Its corresponding page contains PDF links.